# Unable to install matplotlib (virtualenv)

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my first question so apologies about format etc.

I'm trying to do the python exercise on http://newcoder.io/dataviz/part-0/ and I'm attempting to install the pre-requisites for working within a virtualenv.

At the stage

```
(DataVizProj)$ pip install numpy
(DataVizProj)$ pip install matplotlib
```

It seems to install fine. However on testing matplotlib within python itself (running a python terminal and then trying "import matplotlib") I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

I have also tried sudo apt-get build-dep matplotlib but every time I am getting the above error. I have googled to no avail - can anybody assist?

P.s. I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Are you running __python__ from within your virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, I know I am a bit newbie but I can definitely confirm that I run python from within the virtualenv. Furthermore I've followed most of the other instructions on the site listed, it's just this matplotlib being extremely pernickity!

Comment: In your virtualenv directory, can you find the matplotlib package?

Comment: @Hannes - I found, for example numpy in /Envs/DataVizPro/include/python2.7/numpy (Datavizpro is name of my virtual env)... I cannot find matplotlib so perhaps installation failed?

Comment: If your virtualenv does not contain anything called matplotlib, then the installation likely failed. Can you post the output of `pip install matplotlib`?

Comment: Hi you can try and make sense of the output here http://www.pastebin.ca/2517351 .. Clearly a lot of the output was "cut off" in the terminal (not sure how to save output). Plus still can't find the matplotlib directory so I don't believe it was successfully installed.